# IntelliJ shows unresolved reference to java.lang.String#replace in Fabric Kotlin dev environment

Tags: kotlin, intellij-idea, minecraft, minecraft-fabric

```kotlin
class Foo(
        val name: Identifier,
        val trKey: String = "action.${name.toString().replace(':', '.')}"
        //                                            ^~~~~~~ this is unresolved
) {
    // Members
}
```

The replace function is able to be resolved in Fabric's source code and it does run, but it doesn't in my Kotlin code.

I've tried setting the project SDK to 1.8, 11, and Kotlin SDK, and none of them seem to solve this issue. In fact, putting the SDK to 11 makes java.lang.String inaccesible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<strike>I think I fixed it by adding KotlinRuntime into libraries through IntelliJ project structure (will get erased by Gradle import), or with gradle dependencies adding Kotlin library.</strike>
Instead I found changing JDK version back to 1.8 fixes this issue and is reproducable. The above only worked once for me.